# Issue adding element to list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm a total newbie to Flutter and I'm trying to add some data from Cloud Firestore to a list in Flutter, but having issues. I try to add the element, but after executing, the element isn't there. It's not throwing an exception or anything either. Maybe someone else has some advice for me!

I have tried changing the type of list (capture the doc from Cloud Firestore instead of data within the doc, same issue), I have also debugPrinted the data I am trying to store to make sure it exists, it does. I have done basic troubleshooting like running flutter clean as well. I am on the latest version of Flutter.

```
Firestore db = firestore();

List<String> getString() {

var dataList = new List<String>();

db.collection('Users').get().then((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) {
    dataList.add(doc.get('First name'));
  });
});

debugPrint(dataList.first);

return dataList;
```

The list is empty, though it should contain the "First name" field on this Cloud Firestore doc. Again, verified the data does exist and prints when calling debugPrint.

Comment: I have answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db.collection('Users').get()` is a async function, so `debugPrint(dataList.first);` executes before of the end of your firestores get, because that your array returns empty.

If you try it:

```
db.collection('Users').get().then((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) {
    dataList.add(doc.get('First name'));
  });
  debugPrint(dataList.first);
});
```

You will see your data.

You can use `await` to wait the call finishes, so you must return a `Future` and use `async` key word on function declaration. This is a conceipt that you must know of flutter async functions ([Async Flutter](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)). So, the code below can solve your problem.

```
Firestore db = firestore();

Future <List<String>> getString() async {

var dataList = new List<String>();

var result = await db.collection('Users').get();
result.forEach((doc) {
    dataList.add(doc.get('First name'));
  });

debugPrint(dataList.first);

return dataList;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the widget containing the data to be updated occasionally is Stateful and not Stateless.

Comment: The questions says nothing about widget components. But if them are used,of course the widget must be the correct

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense! This code is working. Thanks for the help!